# Create an after trigger that updates a column in another table (SQLplus)

Tags: oracle11g, sqlplus

I need to create a trigger that updates the quantity in the Product table whenever an order of type 2 from `Order_call` table is described in the `Order_line` table.
I have tried the below trigger but I keep getting errors:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER updqty AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON ORDER_LINE FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE
ortype NUMBER(1);
BEGIN 
SELECT @ortype=type FROM ORDER_CALL WHERE orderID=NEW.orderID;
    IF (ortype=2) THEN
    UPDATE PRODUCT SET qty = qty - NEW.qty WHERE part_no=NEW.part_no;
END IF;
END;
```

I have the `Products` table than contains the quantity of each available product, the `Order_call` table that registers the *orderID* and its type (type 2 means it's an actual sale) and the `Order_Line` table where the actual order is detailed. It stores on rows the *orderID*, the *part*_*no*, and the *quantity sold*. So, for each *orderID* of type 2 from the `Order_Call` table I need to take the quantity of each product sold (from `Order_Line`) and subtract it from the qty of the respective *part*_*no* in the `Product` table.

I am receiving the following compilation errors:

```
4/2  PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
4/19 PL/SQL: ORA-00936: missing expression
```

I don't have too much **SQL** experience. 
Thanks for helping.

Comment: @ is for SQL-Server T-SQL.  I suggests you read some of the Oracle documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to get it, if anyone else would need this later on:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER updqty
   BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
   ON ORDER_LINE
   FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   ortype   NUMBER (5);
BEGIN
   SELECT TYPE
     INTO ortype
     FROM ORDER_CALL
    WHERE order_call.orderID = :NEW.orderID;

   IF (ortype = 2)
   THEN
      UPDATE PRODUCT
         SET qty = qty - :NEW.qty
       WHERE part_no = :NEW.part_no;
   END IF;
END;
/
```